# No such module 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK' xCode 14.2

Tags: xcode

I have problem with Xcode 14.2 (using Swift) that has me completely stumped. I realize that this question has been asked and answered, but none of the answers have worked for me, and my situation seems to be a bit different than the others, as all of my pods are failing (not just a specific one). They all worked fine a week ago.